# Fmtlib and Format.h not linked on MAC CLANG

Tags: c++, macos, clang, homebrew, fmt

On Mac, I have installed fmt with Brew and tried to include fmt/format.h with `#include <fmt/format.h>`

But Clang returns this error: `fatal error: 'fmt/format.h' file not found`
I checked out the path and the file exists on my hard drive.

It is included in PATH but this didn't solve it.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: What flags did you use? Are you using a build tool? More information is needed here

Comment: -masm=intel -msyntax=intel -m64 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=TRUE -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=TRUE -lfmt

Comment: Where on your system did brew install the fmt library to and does your compiler invocation look in that path? The PATH variable is used for looking up programs, it has nothing to do with include files.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Xcode, then you need to make it available first.

Go to **Build Settings** for your project (under project navigator, click on first folder matching your project name), and make sure **All** is selected under its subsections. Follow the below steps:

1. Search for **Header Search Paths** to filter the list. Add an entry as following:

```bash
/usr/local/Cellar/fmt/9.1.0/include
```

2. Search for **Library Search Paths** to filter the list. Add an entry as following:

```bash
/usr/local/Cellar/fmt/9.1.0/lib
```

3. Search for **Other Linker Flags** to filter the list. Add an entry as following:

```bash
-lfmt
```

**NOTE**: In above steps, replace `9.1.0` with your installed version and you should be done.

You can check the installed version by running:

```bash
brew info fmt
```

Answer (score 1):

On my ARM-based macOS (M1 chip), rmalviya's answer works with a little twist:
I used `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fmt/9.1.0` instead of `/usr/local/Cellar/fmt/9.1.0 (still need to add suffix)`

Also, I found this blog helpful for setting up the homebrew correctly for ARM-based mac.

Comment: "_Also, I found this blog helpful for setting up the homebrew correctly for ARM-based mac._" what blog?

Comment: I also had to replace: `#include <format>` with `#include "fmt/format.h"` and replace `using std::format;` with `using fmt::format;` in the tutorial/sample code I was using.